# Implicit assumption in simplifying an equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions

So I tried simplify on an equation (see below).

```
( Laplacian[V[r,\[Theta],\[Phi]],{r,\[Theta],\[Phi]},"Spherical" ]  //Simplify)
% == 0 
%//Simplify
```

Now the weird thing was that when I had just the expression on the first line, the code evaluated with r^2 in the denominator. However, after setting that expression == 0 on the second line, and then simplifying on the third line, the denominator became r.

### If Mathematica was going to multiply both sides of the equation by r, then why didn't it just completely eliminate the denominator by multiplying by r^2?

PS. I am a beginner so please don't use anything too complex to explain.

Comment: Probably more simplification steps than `Simplify` wanted to do. Try `FullSimplify` and you'll see that it does more

Comment: `FullSimplify` still doesn't remove remove r because the equation =0. Is there a way to tell simplify to do that?

Comment: Also, I feel like I can't predict what Mathematica is going to do in terms of simplification. I'd like to know a simple way to know what is going to happen when I ask Mathematica to do something.

Comment: To try to guess why it eliminated r, but didn't eliminate r^2... think what it would mean if r was zero. If r^2 was zero you have zero in the denominator, with r you still have zero in the denominator. But if you eliminate r^2 there is no possible zero left in the denominator. You will likely find many things like that if you keep using MMA. It will almost always assume a number could be complex or could be zero. But when you do math by hand you often don't think of those cases and end up doing incorrect steps. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Ion Sme Here is something to mull over: Define `V = {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]} \[Function] r^2` and execute your code afterwards.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Then the Laplacian yields 6. I'm not sure where this is going.

Comment: If you had multiplied by `r^2` then `r == 0` would have become a "solution" for your equation. But of course $6 \neq 0$...

Comment: @Bill How come `FullSimplify` eliminated instances of r/r. Isn't that also changing the domain?

Comment: Sometimes, usually very rarely and more often for badly posed problems, MMA will do things that are questionably or sometimes even likely wrong. Some of those were design decisions made for some deep reason, some of those were simply errors hidden deep inside MMA. If you ever get to a point where you are never surprised by what MMA does then you will have truly become a master, but that is very very unlikely. You should be surprised less often after 10^4 hours of intense study and use.